# Is there any way to make it look like a honeycomb?

Tags: modeling, 3d-view

I am modeling and want to achieve an effect like a picture. I don’t know how to make it like this. What I did looks very bad
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, does your paper need thickness, does it need to be straight or a little bit curvy?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For a more realistic version you'll need to give thickness to the paper (with a bevel on the diagonals) and subdivide a bit so that the paper is not so straight.

Subdivide a plane, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Unsubdivide* with an *Iteration* of 1 in the *Operator* box:

[image]

Delete the faces only, and the borde edges:

[image]

Extrude in order to give it depth, scale on Z:

[image]

Bend it with a Simple Deform modifier, narrow the top with a Lattice:

[image]

Comment: That is a quick method

Comment: thaks, it's minimalistic but the OP doesn't tell a lot

Comment: Wow, thank you so much, there is such a way to subdivide the plane!is a really quick method.